# SQL Server Management Studio hanging every few seconds

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.  SSMS started intermittently hanging every 5 seconds or so today for no apparent reason.  For example, I'm typing code and then the text editor stops updating for about 2 seconds, then suddenly catches up with what I'm typing.  It's making work almost impossible.  I've rebooted but I'm not sure what else to do since it's an SSMS issue - checking it in Task Manager and it's barely using any CPU, although it is using about 1.2 GB of memory.

Anyone experienced this before & know a possible fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some suggestions that might help.

You could try running SQL Profiler, and watch out for any lengthy calls to the database which might 
make it hang.

Have you tried turning off intellisense? `Options -> Text Editor -> Transact-SQL -> IntelliSense -> Untick Enable IntelliSense`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response - I just thought of turning off intellisense after posting that and it seems to have fixed it...for now anyway.

Comment: I'd put my money on intellisense for sure.  Whenever you get to a place where it needs to give you suggestions, it's going to the database to figure out what makes sense.  If the connection between you and the server is slow, it'll hang.  I wish MS had put that in a separate thread to keep the UI from hanging, but it is what it is.

Comment: I was having the same problem, connecting to a remote server over broadband. Since turning off intellisense a couple of weeks ago the problem has disappeared completely.